# How to match the horizontal collectionView Cell's width on it's content size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I know some related questions already there regarding this but I tried those before and still no luck.

Here is my problem on the following screenshot 
[image: my current collectionView]
My current screen shows a fixed cell size and it displays empty spaces for smaller contents and larger contents going over the cell with dots..

I wanted like below 
[image]
it should match the width of the product category name content.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.catCollectionView{
        let catCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "catCell", for: indexPath)
            as! catCell

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            catCell.configureCell()

            let catCountInt = self.catCountArray[indexPath.row]


            catCell.catCountLabel.text = String(catCountInt)
            catCell.catNameLabel.text = self.categoryNameArray[indexPath.row]
            catCell.catCountLabel.sizeToFit()
            catCell.catNameLabel.sizeToFit()

        }
        return catCell
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let catCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "catCell", for: indexPath)
        as! catCell
    catCell.catNameLabel.text = self.categoryNameArray[indexPath.item]
    catCell.catNameLabel.sizeToFit()
     let labelWidth = catCell.catNameLabel.frame.width + 10
    print("frame width: \(labelWidth)")
    return CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: 21)
}
```

}

Maybe I'm missing a simple thing here but I couldn't quite figure out at this moment. Please help me and sorry for my strange English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's imagine you are using a simple `UICollectionViewCell` subclass with constraints set up correctly in storyboard (label is pinned to all four sides of its superview) like this:

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

}
```

Then you can simply let auto layout determine the cells' sizes:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let categories = [
        "All Products",
        "Fresh",
        "Health & Beauty",
        "Beverages",
        "Home & life"
    ]

    private var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? {
        return collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white

        flowLayout?.sectionInset = .init(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
        flowLayout?.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
        flowLayout?.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.flowLayout?.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: Hi, does it work for prototype cell?. I tried with a prototype cell but not working

Comment: You mean a prototype cell in storyboard?

Comment: Yes prototype cell in storyboard

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `dequeuing` another `cell` in `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, you can simply calculate the `width` of `categoryName` using `size(withAttributes:)` on the `categoryName`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let text = self.categoryNameArray[indexPath.row] {
    let cellWidth = text.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:14.0)]).width + 10.0
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 21.0)
}
```

in `attributes`, give whatever `font` you want the `categoryName` to be.

Comment: how to set a custom font here?

Comment: In the array where I set the value of `.font`, you can set other attributes as well. Example: `.font: UIFont(name: "YOUR_FONT_NAME", size: 15.0)`

Comment: No, not yet. when I use   if let text = self.categoryNameArray[indexPath.item] {  
 I am receiving this error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Comment: This must be because categoryNameArray is not optional. I’ve updated the answer. Try it now.

Comment: when I remove if from text, there is another error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type '(Int, () -> _)'"